# Is the \ escaping of a char in the formatter a bug or just difficult to get right for every language?

Tags: bug, status-deferred, markdown, source-code

In Delphi the \ does not escape a string ending, in Delphi if you want a ' you type:

```
StringVariable := 'Foo'' bar'; // comments
```

And it works as expected, but in [an answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438260/delphi-fast-file-copy/438323#438323) I've always noticed a bug.

I've been able to create a small test case for this bug

```
StringVariable  := '\'; // comments
```

I think formatter has a preference for the c# / c style languages where the \ escapes the next char, so I'm not sure if this is a bug or a feature, this might even be a weird way of asking for a way to instruct the formatter that it's dealing Delphi...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's open source -- submit a patch!

http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/

Comment: should have checked out which library you used instead of assuming that just like mark-down you created a fork from a known library. Will check out how viable a patch is.

Answer (score 2):

Your last suggestion, to make the syntax highlighter language-aware, is the only fool-proof solution for this and similar problems. Hopefully one day this feature will be added to SO.